# Can you tune the update frequency for a Response Parsed Body Dynamic Value?

Tags: paw-app

I have a request this requires a custom HTTP header which has the value of a session id. The header is obtained by doing another request and parsing the json response using Response Parsed Body Dynamic Value.

What are my options in regards to update frequency? Can I say that the value should be parsed every time or specify some sort of interval?

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic value will always take the value from the last response of the referenced request, it does not refresh that request. If you want to fire both request you can put them in a group and order them vertically in the order you want them to fire. Then select the group and click `send all requests`